# how to merge two files to skip duplicate data

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, gawk, join

I have two different large files (each one more than 300,000 lines) and I want to combine them in a specific way. Some rows of the two data measure the same thing; when columns 9, 14, 15, 16, 17 are reciprocally equal, I suppose they are measuring the same thing and I want to output from file1 and skip the file2 rows in order to skip duplicate data. Otherwise, I want to output all rows from both files. The other columns in the duplicate rows may not be equal reciprocally, and the precision of file 1 is better than file 2, and that is the reason for choosing rows from file1 rather than file 2.

For example, since columns 9, 14, 15, 16, and 17 of the three first lines of the two following files are reciprocally equal, so the first three lines of the two datasets measure the same thing and thus I want to output from File 1 and skip the File2 data. For the fourth lines of the datasets, since columns 14 of the two files are not reciprocally equal. I output both lines from two files.

I used this script

```
awk '!seen[$9,$14,$15,$16,$17]++' File1 File2 > output
```

, which works well for small data. However, when I use it for large data sets, it skips some not duplicate data and I dont know the reason. It is deeply appreciated if anyone could help which script I can use for merging the datasets.

File1

```
28  208   48  198  1110   2.04   33 0.0   34.40 3.3 0.0 0   8.0 1985  1  1 SMO1   -9 -9 -9  
24  102   26   99  2100   2.61  129 0.0   42.90 3.3 0.0 0   8.0 1985  1  1 EYA    -9 -9 -9  
89  294   26  106  1162   4.54 -115 0.0   70.80 3.3 0.0 0   8.0 1985  1  1 GYA    -9 -9 -9  
38   88   41   86  1100   3.50  155 0.0   56.30 3.8 0.0 0  10.0 1985  1  1 KOL1   -9 -9 -9
```

File2

```
24  102   22  100  1110   2.04   33 0.0   34.40 3.3 0.0 0   8.0 1985  1  1 SMO1   -9 -9 -9  
24  102   26   99  2100   2.61  129 0.0   42.90 3.3 0.0 0   8.0 1985  1  1 EYA    -9 -9 -9  
24  102   26  106  1162   4.54 -115 0.0   70.80 3.3 0.0 0   8.0 1985  1  1 GYA    -9 -9 -9  
38   88   41   86  1100   3.50  155 0.0   56.30 3.8 0.0 0  10.0 2000  1  1 KOL1   -9 -9 -9
```

output

```
28  208   48  198  1110   2.04   33 0.0   34.40 3.3 0.0 0   8.0 1985  1  1 SMO1   -9 -9 -9  
24  102   26   99  2100   2.61  129 0.0   42.90 3.3 0.0 0   8.0 1985  1  1 EYA    -9 -9 -9  
89  294   26  106  1162   4.54 -115 0.0   70.80 3.3 0.0 0   8.0 1985  1  1 GYA    -9 -9 -9  
38   88   41   86  1100   3.50  155 0.0   56.30 3.8 0.0 0  10.0 1985  1  1 KOL1   -9 -9 -9  
38   88   41   86  1100   3.50  155 0.0   56.30 3.8 0.0 0  10.0 2000  1  1 KOL1   -9 -9 -9
```

Comment: I don't think the commas in the key concatenation do what you think they do - try `[$9 "," $14 "," $15 "," $16 "," $17]` or perhaps more simply `[$9 FS $14 FS $15 FS $16 FS $17]`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for your response. It did not change the situation. It still skips some non_duplicate ones for large data sets. Could you please share your opinion about the possible reason for skipping?

Comment: @Esi I think if you want to debug the reason for the alleged false negatives, you will have to provide a small input/output pair showing the problem.  That is to say, find a pair of records that should not be treated as identical, but which are so treated.